# javascript drawimage height incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drawimage

i have this image [Image Link](https://s13.postimg.org/rmk2wq6uf/depan.jpg) and i want to put that image into canvas
but the result height and width did not accurate
this is my script

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');
img.src = "https://s13.postimg.org/rmk2wq6uf/depan.jpg";
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ekw9n3et/)
please help

Comment: Do you want image to match the canvas size or canvas size match with the current image size?

Comment: That's becuase no `width` and `height` is specified for canvas. Canvas is taking up default values.

Comment: i want canvas size match with original image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the height and width of the `canvas` programmatically using `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`:

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/wbxnkuq4/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "https://s13.postimg.org/rmk2wq6uf/depan.jpg";
canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width,    img.height,
                   0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Im_Saajan/ekw9n3et/2/

check this jsfiddle